# Admob interstitial doesn't work

Tags: swift, admob, gadinterstitial

I'm dealing with the Admob interstitials and in particular I'm trying to display an interstitial when a particular `ViewController` of my app loads. I used the code provided by the official Admob Interstitial guide but it doesn't work :https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial?hl=it. I also followed this video here :https://youtu.be/ahmQQ3OeY0Y?t=787 (minute 13.04 stop the video). If you look at the code is the same as in the guide. My objective is to display the ad when the `RequestViewController` appears so I try to present the ad in the `viewDidAppear` function. Anyway it doesn't work, the console displays this error:

> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices =
>   @[ kGADSimulatorID ]

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import GoogleMobileAds

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,GADInterstitialDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

        GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "ca-app-pub-*******")
    }
}
```

This is the ViewController where I present the ad:

**RequestviewController.swift**

```
class RequestViewController: UIViewController {

var myInterstitial : GADInterstitial?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    //display ad

    myInterstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()

    if (myInterstitial?.isReady)!{
        print("\n\n\n\n\nReady")
        myInterstitial?.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }else { print("\n\n\n\nAd wasn't ready") }
}

func createAndLoadInterstitial()->GADInterstitial {
    let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")  //test Ad unit id
    interstitial.delegate = self
    interstitial.load(GADRequest())
    return interstitial
}
func interstitialDidReceiveAd(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    print("interstitialDidReceiveAd")
}

func interstitial(ad: GADInterstitial!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError!) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    print("\n\n\n\n\n\ninterstitialDidDismissScreen")
    myInterstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
}
```

Comment: using inerstitial ad at launch of app is disallowed practice, please avoid - https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en

Comment: Add a check point if interstitial.isReady { } before present.. I belive ur problem is it's not ready to be shown on ViewDidAppear. Instead of implementing this in this viewcontroller. Implement code on back of another viewcontroller

Comment: @AmodGokhale i don't present the ad when i launch the app, the Ad should come out later

Comment: yes check if your code is executed with isReady block. try logger statements in isReady and else code

Comment: if (appDelegate.myInterstitial?.isReady)!{
            print("\n\n\n\n\nReady")
            appDelegate.myInterstitial?.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        }

Comment: if interstitial.isReady {
    interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
  } else {
    print("Ad wasn't ready")
  }

Comment: I did like this and the first time the console displays Ready and the ad appears then i try to reopen the view and nothing is printed. How is it possible that the ad is not ready ? is a test ad ...

Comment: So do you have any suggestion on how to get this interstitial ready again ?

Comment: is it printing Ad wasn't ready? in logs? please visit https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial to get correct implementation ..

Comment: Yes it prints (Ad wasn't ready) . Anyway ,i already visited the website you mentioned but the implementation i found there didn't work for me.

Comment: now i figured out your problem -  interstitial.load(GADRequest()) is called in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions  ( Which will only be called once in lifetime of app). You need to move this code to ViewWillAppear of viewcontroller in question

Comment: I moved the code to the ViewController :  appDelegate.myInterstitial = appDelegate.createAndLoadInterstitial() , in the viewDidAppear , but now i get the following error:<Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ] . The first time, i wrote che code in the Admob guide , all in the RequestViewController ,without using the AppDelegate , but i tried every combination , i tryied to use reques.testDevices but this error was displayed every time. The only way i presented the Ad was by using this solution with the AppDelegate. I'm getting mad. :((((

Comment: Stop this video at the minute 13.00 and look at the code: https://youtu.be/ahmQQ3OeY0Y?t=781

Comment: I tryied to do the exact same thing which is also the code they suggest you into the official Admbo Interstitial guide but nothing, the same stupid error:<Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ]. I'm not able to understand why it works for the guy in the video and not for me!!!

Comment: update your question with latest code that you rewritten so that i can take a look..

Comment: @AmodGokhale Thank you for the support and the patience. I updated the code as you can se.

Comment: What version of Admob you are using? Also let's try to test our code on click of button ( instead of viewdidappear). Try to run code if (myInterstitial?.isReady)!{
        print("\n\n\n\n\nReady")
        myInterstitial?.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }else { print("\n\n\n\nAd wasn't ready") }
 on click of a button

Comment: I'm not able to find the version but i followed this guide here: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/download?hl=it , so i suppose it is 7.2 but i'm not sure.I also tryied with a test button and when i click it i get: "Ad wasn't ready" and after this i get the usual "To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ]." error.

Comment: Updated answer with working code.. Regarding kGADSimulatorID you just need to add that line in your code.. take a look at https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/targeting for adding simulatorID

Comment: I solved the problem using this solution: https://github.com/DanielStormApps/Shared-AdMob-Interstitial

Comment: That's great. above solution should also work.. but not sure why not working in your copy

Comment: @AmodGokhale I know is strange...anyway, thank you really much for the help and for your time!

Answer (score 0):

you need to write it like,

```
appDelegate.createAndLoadInterstitial()
```

in place of,

```
appDelegate.myInterstitial?.present(fromRootViewController: self)
```

Comment: But if do so the ad won't be presented.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the root problem is this section of RequestViewController:

```
myInterstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()

if (myInterstitial?.isReady)!{
    print("\n\n\n\n\nReady")
    myInterstitial?.present(fromRootViewController: self)
}else { print("\n\n\n\nAd wasn't ready") }
```

Interstitials are loaded asynchronously, which means the call to `load()` will return before the ad is loaded and ready to display. If your app is calling `load()` in `createAndLoadInterstitial` and then checking `isReady` immediately afterwards, there's no time for the ad to actually load, and `isReady` will always be false.

A good way to deal with this could be to create the interstitial in your *first* view controller, and then show it *before* transitioning to `RequestViewController`. That would give the ad time to load, and would still display it during the same transition.

FWIW, transition time between ViewControllers is a great place in the flow of your app to use an interstitial, so well done there.

Also, the line:

> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ]

isn't an error. The Android and iOS SDKs always print that to the log so publishers will know how to get test ads for a particular device or emulator. If you were running on a hardware device instead of the iOS simulator, you'd see a unique identifier for the device in that line, which you could then use in your code to get test ads.